# XOR neural network with python

Tags: python, neural-network

I developed a neural network representing an XOR gate using the sigmoid function as the activation function and the loss function as the objective function.
the question is to let **the training continues while the training error is above 0.3**

```
import numpy as np 
np.random.seed(0)

def sigmoid (x):
    # compute and return the sigmoid activation value for a
    # given input value
    return 1.0/(1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    # compute the derivative of the sigmoid function
    return x * (1 - x)

def loss(residual):
    # compute the loss function
    return residual * residual

def loss_derivative(residual):
    # compute the derivative of the loss function
    return 2 * residual

    

#Define the inputs and stucture of neural network
# XOR Inputs
inputs = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
# XOR Output
expected_output = np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])

# Learning rate
lr = 0.1
# Number of neurons
n_x = 2
n_h = 2
n_y = 1

#Random weights initialization
hidden_weights = np.random.rand(n_x,n_h)
output_weights = np.random.rand(n_h,n_y)


print("Initial hidden weights: ",end='')
print(*hidden_weights)
print("Initial output weights: ",end='')
print(*output_weights)



#Training algorithm
# loop over each individual data point and train
# the network on it
count = 0
while(True):
    # FEEDFORWARD:
    # feedforward the activation at the current layer by
    # taking the dot product between the activation and the weight matrix 
    hidden_layer_activation = np.dot(inputs,hidden_weights)
    hidden_layer_output = sigmoid(hidden_layer_activation)

    output_layer_activation = np.dot(hidden_layer_output,output_weights)
    predicted_output = loss(output_layer_activation)

    # BACKPROPAGATION
    #the first phase of backpropagation is to compute the
    # difference between the *prediction* and the true target value y-ŷ
    error = predicted_output - expected_output 
    if (error < 0.3).any():   break
    d_predicted_output = error * loss_derivative(predicted_output)
    
    error_hidden_layer = d_predicted_output.dot(output_weights.T)
    d_hidden_layer = error_hidden_layer * sigmoid_derivative(hidden_layer_output)

    #Updating Weights 
    output_weights += hidden_layer_output.T.dot(d_predicted_output) * lr
    hidden_weights += inputs.T.dot(d_hidden_layer) * lr
    
print("Final hidden weights: ",end='')
print(*hidden_weights)

print("Final output weights: ",end='')
print(*output_weights)

print("\nOutput from neural network after learning: ",end='')
print(*predicted_output)
```

but when I write a condition like

```
if (error < 0.3).any():   break
```

the program does only one iteration and then stop

can anyone tell me what the problem is with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the absolute error, as if it underpredicts, the error is negative:

```
np.abs(error < 0.3).any()
```

However, you also probably want the mean error:

```
np.mean(np.abs(error)) < 0.3
```

Comment: thank you, I tried both. unfortunately, it doesn't work. still do one iteration and stopped